# How does Soti's MobiControl for Android install apps?

Tags: android, soti

Even with the unknown sources setting disabled ( no installation from non google play sources ) MobiControl is still able to install apps. How does it achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Soti uses the Google EMM APIs to install apps. This requires an elevated special relationship with Google to access. For info on the APIs see: https://developers.google.com/android/work/distribute#push-installed_vs_user-installed_apps

For info on becoming part of the EMM community see: https://connect.googleforwork.com/community/applicants/android/emm